# TypeError: DateTime::__construct() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in DateTime->__construct() - Drupal 8

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-8

I am trying to save datecriteriamet date field to the backend and below is my function:

```
public function render(ResultRow $values) {
    $id = $values->id;
    $program = Program::load($id);
    $progname = $program->getProgramName();
    $lastreviewed = $program->getLastreviewed();
    $criteriamet = $program->getcriteriamet();
    $datecriteriamet = $program->getdatecriteriamet();
    $path = Url::fromRoute('cca.show-program', ['cca_program' => $id])->toString();

    if ($lastreviewed != '' && $datecriteriamet = '' && $criteriamet != 1) {
        $date = date_create($lastreviewed);
        $lastreviewed_date = $date->format('M Y');
        return "<a href='${path}'></a>Last reviewed date: $lastreviewed_date";
    } elseif ($datecriteriamet != '' && $criteriamet == 1) {
    $criteriametdate = date_create($datecriteriamet);
    $datecriteriamet_date = $criteriametdate->format('M Y');
    return "<a href='${path}'></a>Date Criteria Met: $datecriteriamet_date
    <br>
    <br>
     } else {
              return "<a href='${path}'><button class='testclass2'>$progname</button></a>";
        }
    }
```

The function is returning data correctly and everything works fine when the date field is having a value. When datecriteriamet is NULL, I get to see:

```
TypeError: DateTime::__construct() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in DateTime->__construct()
```

Not sure how to fix this. Can someone help?

Comment: Can't be `NULL`, because the error message clearly says: `...expects parameter 1 to be string, array given...` ... what does function `getdatecriteriamet` return? Must be an array, even if an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

Function `date_create` (an alias of `DateTime::__construct()`) requires that the first argument must be string. You need to make sure that function `getdatecriteriamet()` always returns a string.